# Run docker-compose within docker in Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, google-cloud-run

I have a system I have tested on compute engine where I boot up a docker-compose system that exposes some ports to localhost, and then communicate to that over python-flask. I am looking to bring this to Google Cloud Run, however when I attempt to run the docker daemon with systemd or dockerd I end up receiving messages like this:

`failed to start daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted`

Which lead to these errors when calling docker compose:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Is there a straightforward way to start the docker daemon on google cloud run environments? Currently using ubuntu 22.04 image as base.

Comment: No, you can't. Google Cloud Run is not built on Docker. It is built on gVisor. Things like cgroup do not exist. Some features that an OS provides do not exist inside a container. A key point to remember is that a container does not provide an operating system. There is a layer inside the container that interfaces with the host operating system. That is why you cannot run a Windows container on Linux (as an example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki from the comment of @JohnHanley:

> No, you can't. Google Cloud Run is not built on Docker. It is built on gVisor. Things like cgroup do not exist. Some features that an OS provides do not exist inside a container. A key point to remember is that a container does not provide an operating system. There is a layer inside the container that interfaces with the host operating system. That is why you cannot run a Windows container on Linux (as an example).